# Read-Only Property in C# 6.0

Tags: c#, properties, c#-6.0

Microsoft introduce a new syntax in C#6 that let you set your property to read-only as below:

```
public class Animal
{
    public string MostDangerous { get; } = "Mosquito";
}
```

I am wondering what is the added value of such approach.

What is the difference by just writing:

```
public class Animal
{
    public const string MostDangerous = "Mosquito";
}
```

or even:

```
public class Animal
{
    public string MostDangerous 
    { 
        get
        {
            return "Mosquito";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What about something like: `public DateTime CreationTime { get; } = DateTime.Now;`?

Comment: See this article to see what's behind the new C# 6 features: https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/whats-new-in-c-6/

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your example is using string constants which can't show all the possibilities. Look at this snippet:

```
class Foo
{
    public DateTime Created { get; } = DateTime.Now;  // construction timestamp

    public int X { get; } 

    public Foo(int n)
    {
        X = n;  // writeable in constructor only
    }
}
```

Read only properties are per-instance and can be set from the constructor. Very different from a `const` field whose value must be determined at compile time. The property initializer is a separate feature and follows the rules and limitations of field initializers.

Answer (score 2):

The newer syntax is an effort in reducing the verbosity of C#. It's just syntactic sugar. The IL generated is similar to an auto property with a getter and a backing store.

Answer (score 1):

This improvement to C# was taken directly from VB, and removes the need to implement the backing field and constructor initializer:

```vb
Public ReadOnly dateStamp As DateTime = Datetime.Now
```

Comment: VB's auto property was taken directly from C#