# Read-Only Auto-Property for Simple Types: Initializer VS Expression Body Getter

Tags: c#, c#-6.0, automatic-properties

In C# 6.0, the new syntax let us write read-only auto-properties with using an initializer:

```cs
public bool AllowsDuplicates { get; } = true;
```

Likewise, we can write it using an expression body getter:

```cs
public bool AllowsDuplicates => true;
```

For simple types, these two should have the same effect: a read-only auto-property that returns true.

But is one of them preferred over the other? I suspect that the former uses a backing field:

```cs
private readonly bool _backingField = true;
public bool AllowsDuplicates {
    get {
        return _backingField;
    }
}
```

Whereas the latter is turned into something like:

```cs
public bool AllowsDuplicates {
    get {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Is that right, or is the compiler smarter than this?

Comment: The point is a little moot, as a `public const` would be more appropriate for this case. For the rest, very similar to [this recent question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36820229/)

Comment: @HenkHolterman No, I don't believe it is. I'm specifically asking about simple types.

Comment: But why use properties at all for this kind of values?

Comment: Because the property is defined in an interface ;) And moreover, you should rather expose a property than a field, since that will allow you to change it the internal implementation later on, without breaking clients code.

Comment: So there is (might be) a tiny difference in space used, not really something you would ever notice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I suspect that the former uses a backing field

The auto-property initializer does in fact creating a backing field! You can throw this in ILSpy and see it in the output:

```
public class One
{
    public bool AllowsDuplicates
    {
        [CompilerGenerated]
        get
        {
            return this.<AllowsDuplicates>k__BackingField;
        }
    }

    public One()
    {
        this.<AllowsDuplicates>k__BackingField = true;
        base..ctor();
    }
}

public class Two
{
    public bool AllowsDuplicates
    {
        get
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

> But is one of them preferred over the other?

For the *specific example in the question*, the auto-property would allow a constructor to ask for a `bool` and assign it. The second style would not. If the intent is to use it as a "default value" which can be modified once during construction, then an auto-property is the right choice.

```
class Test
{
    // Could assign this in the second constructor
    public bool AllowsDuplicates { get; } = true;

    // Cannot assign this in the second constructor
    public bool AllowsDuplicates => true;

    public Test()
    {
        // Default value used
    }

    public Test(bool value)
    {
        AllowsDuplicates = value;
    }
}
```

I've seen expression bodied syntax win out most when it's a cover for a small function that is utilized as a property. A struct in [Eric Lippert's dedoublifier](https://ericlippert.com/2015/11/30/the-dedoublifier-part-one/) has a nice example of this:

```
public DoubleHelper(double d)
{
    this.RawBits = (ulong)BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(d);
}

public ulong RawBits { get; }
// RawSign is 1 if zero or negative, 0 if zero or positive
public int RawSign => (int)(RawBits >> 63);
public int RawExponent => (int)(RawBits >> 52) & 0x7FF;
public long RawMantissa => (long)(RawBits & 0x000FFFFFFFFFFFFF);
public bool IsNaN => RawExponent == 0x7ff && RawMantissa != 0;
public bool IsInfinity => RawExponent == 0x7ff && RawMantissa == 0;
public bool IsZero => RawExponent == 0 && RawMantissa == 0;
public bool IsDenormal => RawExponent == 0 && RawMantissa != 0;
```

There's one value which is assigned in the constructor, and the rest are property values which are computed based off of it.

Comment: The first part of you answer is right. But from "But is one of them preferred over the other?" you no longer focus on **simple types**, which the question is about. `DateTime.Now` is not a simple type; it is a property (that should have been implemented as a method) that returns a simple type.

Comment: @MikkelR.Lund I've updated the answer to focus on the specific example in the question.

Answer (score 3):

> I suspect that the former uses a backing field, whereas the latter is
>   turned into something like, Is that right?

Yes, it's like you said, *Auto-property Initializer* set the value of the backing field at the moment of the declaration.

And the *Expression-bodied* is a syntax simplification for the `get` body.

> But is one of them preferred over the other?

Depends, if your property is more complex that just returning the same value, for example, like an `Elapsed` or `Current` property, or anything that needs to be computed an *Expression-bodied* is more suitable.
In an *Expression-bodied* you define the code to be executed each time the property is accessed.

If your property is supposed to be immutable, just an initial constant value then *Auto-property Initializer* would be preferred.

Comment: "If your property is supposed to be immutable, just an initial constant value then Auto-property Initializer would be preferred." But is this really the case, if the contant value is a simple type as in the question?

Comment: @MikkelR.Lund: I think you can apply quite well for simple types, if your property behaves like a constant, then use auto-property initializers, but if your property need to be computed (like an Count) then Expression-Bodied is the only choice.