# Read-only property without private set;

Tags: c#, properties, readonly-attribute

Shouldn't I define `private set;` if I want to set `A` property in Foo instance. Or is this implicitly done by c#?

```
public class Foo
{
    public string A { get; }

    public Foo(string a)
    {
        this.A = a;
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
  Foo a = new Foo("sfd");
  string b = a.A; // sfd
}
```

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36820229/read-only-property-in-c-sharp-6-0

Comment: Ah it's writable in constructor only. I want to find Microsoft documentation on this.

Comment: _"I want to find Microsoft documentation on this"_ -- where have you looked? _have_ you looked? Because the C# language documentation at learn.microsoft.com is comprehensive, and of course includes complete details on this and other forms of property declarations.